# ruby on rails memory leak

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory-leaks

rails 2.3.14, ruby 1.8.7

i have a rake task:

```
    Post.all.each do |post|

      post.comments.each { |pc|
        pc.delete
      }
      user = post.user

      pc = user.comment.build(
          :text => 'Test text',
      ......
      )
      result = pc.send_comment_http

      if result.success?
        pc.save!
      else
        puts error_message
      end
    end
```

Post have 100k row and task run 50h alredy, row are added every 3 seconds in db, it not problem, but ps -ax | grep rake indicates that occupied 2 gb. What could be the problem memory leak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
Post.find_each do |post|
  ...    
end
```

Comment: yes, you are right. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects "But this approach becomes increasingly impractical as the table size increases, since User.all.each instructs Active Record to fetch the entire table in a single pass, build a model object per row, and then keep the entire array of model objects in memory. Indeed, if we have a large number of records, the entire collection may exceed the amount of memory available."

Answer (score 3):

The iterations on comments. The second loop you can avoid it by: `post.comments.destroy_all`

Also, when an user makes a comment, I can see it is not related to a post (because an user can have many posts, right?), so you can divide the operations. First truncate directly the comments table, second get the users that are related to a post (you can use `join` and `group by`, or just use `join` if you want that for each post sent a message), third loop over the users and send the message.

Comment: your decision should speed up, but it certainly will not solve the problem memory leak.

Comment: delete_all is ok, but should be used carefully, becase it doesn't trigger ActiveRecord callbacks